# Why Firefox ignores custom font from @font-face?

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

Let’s say we have a font-face section like that

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'F';
   src: url("/fonts/F.eot?") format("embedded-opentype"); 
   src: local('?'),
        url("/fonts/F.woff") format("woff"),
        url("/fonts/F.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("/fonts/F.svg") format("svg"); 
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

and a body style

```
body {
font-family: 'F' /*, sans-serif*/;
}
```

Now, if I uncomment sans-serif it will take priority over custom font despite the fact it is mentioned at the end. Why? How do I specify a back-up variant for those who can’t use downloadable webfonts?

**===upd===**

If in doubt why `local('?')` is used, look here http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/#smiley

I was wrong in my thinking that it is `sans-serif` breaking my CSS, here is actual code that shows custom 'F' font. If 'Trebuchet MS' will be uncommented, font-family drops to sans.

```
body {
font-family: 'F' /*, 'Trebuchet MS'*/ , sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems to be slightly incorrect. The '?' at the end of the first 'src' property value is aimed towards fixing IE versions 6 through 8, but could actually be affecting Firefox. The correct syntax to use is:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'MyWebFont';
        src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
        src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
             url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
             url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
             url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
        }
```

Source: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax

Comment: Alright, I fixed code to this version, but it didn’t the trick.
And '?' purpose there is not for IE.

Comment: If you're using the above syntax and it still isn't working then unfortunately something else is wrong. Either you are declaring the family incorrectly later in the CSS, or perhaps the font file simply cannot be read. Is this problem isolated to Firefox?

Comment: Look, I change only the string describing the font for document body. There is no redeclarations for body font except of one place in the title, but I have no claims for it, I cannot understand is it a special Firefox behavior or what. I do not rename font files, move them or anything else. I just removing `'Trebuchet MS'` and my custom font becomes displayable. And yes it is only Firefox issue.

Comment: Could you perhaps upload the files somewhere so I could see the problem? Without seeing it for myself it's going to be hard to debug.

Comment: Here after some cleaning is a page where the subj can be seen (fonts included) http://ompldr.org/vZnFsMA

Comment: I'm not sure if this was a symptom of you saving the page from your browser, but the font files are not being linked properly in the CSS file. The CSS file attempts to find 'PTS55F.eot', when the filename is actually 'PTS55F_W.eot'. Moreover, once updating the syntax and linking to the files properly I saw no issue in Firefox or any other browser. I would advise you remove all font declarations out of the CSS and start again, including the font using the updated syntax.

Comment: Ahem, really… I am sure that custom font work but file names didn’t match, I used to set local() with actual font name, may it be that firefox has remembered font by its actual name and then used? Cause this is strange. BTW with correct filenames I have no CSS issues.